# React navigation example JS grammar

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I don't understand where is the `navigation` from (line 46-48 ):

https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/blob/master/examples/NavigationPlayground/js/StacksOverTabs.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`const MyHomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => (
  <MyNavScreen banner="Home Screen" navigation={navigation} />
);`

is equal to

```
class MyHomeScreen extends React.Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props);
}

render(){

    const {navigation} = this.props;

    return <MyNavScreen banner="Home Screen" navigation={navigation} />
}}
```

Comment: what is 'const {navigation} = this.props;'

Comment: this equal to 'const navigation = this.props.navigation'

Comment: thanks very much, how do you know these?  where could I find the document ?

Comment: this is not react native grammar, it is from new ECMAScript grammar.